# How do we know that the limit of the Fourier sums exist?

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do we know that the limit of the partial sums of the Fourier expansion exists? Can it happen that for an integrable function limit superior and limit inferior of the partial sums are unequal at some point?

Comment: There are sufficient conditions, like [Dirichlet's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) that, if satisfied, ensure convergence.

Comment: On the other hand, there are L^1 functions whose Fourier series diverges everywhere. And even the Fourier series of a continuous function can diverge at some points.

Comment: You are referring to pointwise convergence I presume. The limit can exist in other senses as well, for example $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: The pointwise convergence is proved for L^2 for example. I wan`t to know how we know that the series is well defined in some sense that I cannot exactly express. The examples I have seen have Fourier series diverging to infinity.

Comment: I meant to say that the a.e convergence is proved for L^2.

Comment: A difficult theorem, the Carlesson-Hunt theorem, give you almost everywhere convergence for $f \in L^p$ and $p > 1$. In $p = 1$ as Thorgott said there is a counterexample due to Kolmogorov. I gave some references already in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227007/how-to-understand-the-convergence-of-fourier-series-in-lp/3228215#3228215

Comment: OK. If the series is well defined, from $L_p$ convergence for $p > 1$ we can trivially deduct the a.e convergence, because then there is a subsequence  converging a.e. But in $L_1$ we don't have norm convergence. I was wondering can those series still be well defined in some sense, even though they can be infinite.